# How to repeat video with start and end time in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm getting error in Android Studio on second "cannot resolve symbol second" how to fix it so that it loops from 358 to 331 in this example?

```
package com.example.myapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;

public class FingerStretching extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finger_stretching);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);

        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            String videoId = "mSZWSQSSEjE";
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 331);
            }
            
            public void onCurrentSecond(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                if(second == 358) youTubePlayer.seekTo(331);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

tried creating local variable second

Comment: The error says itself. In `second == 358`, The variable `second` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/blob/3b17fe9b69398bae570392b34caa1c234dcbaa28/core/src/main/java/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/core/player/listeners/AbstractYouTubePlayerListener.kt#LL16C16-L16C31), the signature of `onCurrentSecond` is

```kotlin
override fun onCurrentSecond(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, second: Float)
```

You are not overriding it. It should be

```java
@Override
public void onCurrentSecond(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, float second) {
    if(second >= 358) youTubePlayer.seekTo(331);
}
```

Such kind of error is easily avoidable if you make use of the auto complete feature in the IDE. Typing `onC` within the `AbstractYouTubePlayerListener` should give you auto complete option for `onCurrentSecond`, selecting it should automatically write the override function for you with correct signature.

Comment: Thanks, for that. I tried the code but it's not looping back to 331, any ideas?

Comment: @nCalibi You are not likely to get `second` exactly equal to `358` because it is a decimal number. Try `second >= 358` instead.